# Picard's theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a very simple question. On the proof of Picard's theorem about the existence and uniqueness of a solution to a differential equation, we have to prove that the map T defined by
$$(T\varphi)(t)=x_0+\int_{t_0}^{t} f(s,\varphi(s))\,ds$$
maps $M$ into $M$, where $M$ is a closed subset of $C(I)$. I think the first thing we need to check is that the integral exists. Why does the integral
$\int_{t_0}^{t} f(s,\varphi(s))\,ds$ exists?

Comment: Because the map $\Bbb R\ni s\mapsto f(s,\varphi(s))\in\Bbb R^n$ is continuous.

Comment: (at least, in the version I know $f:\Bbb R^{1+n}\to\Bbb R^n$ is continuous + the Lipschitz stuff).

Answer (score 1):

The integral exists because the function being integrated $f(x,y)$ is referred as a continuous function in PICARD'S THEOREM!